# plotly locationmode for the whole world

Tags: plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to create a choropleth map for some data of the whole world and I am using `plotly` to do it but found that `locationmode` examples are all on Usa-States

Is there a way for me to use it on the world

Comment: There are other examples in the official reference. [python](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#using-builtin-country-and-state-geometries) [R](https://plotly.com/r/choropleth-maps/#using-builtin-country-and-state-geometries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `plotly` [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/scatter-plots-on-maps/).
Givent that you have a `DataFrame` of `lats` ond `lons`:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scattergeo(
        lon = df['lon'],
        lat = df['lat'],
        mode = 'markers',
        ))

fig.update_layout(
        title = 'world map with markers',
        geo_scope='world',
    )
fig.show()
```